# how to turn a "new" resource into post and get?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'd like to be able to do a post request on my new resource route and am having trouble. Currently I have this in my `routes.rb` file

```
resources :shipments, only: [:new] do
end
```

and I've tried putting `post :new` in between the block but that gives me

`shipments POST     /:slug/shipments(.:format)       shipments#new`

but I want this

`new_product_shipment GET|POST   /:slug/shipment/new(.:format)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it lik this:

```
resources :orders, only: [:new] do
  collection do
    post 'new'
  end
end
```

But, by the way - it is very strange decision to have both methods on single action.

Comment: that ends up giving me `shipments POST     /:slug/shipments(.:format)       shipments#new`, anyway to just combine it with new? or should I just make a new route entirely using match and `via: [:get, :post]`

Comment: @cvDv are you use `post 'new'` and not `post :new`? And sure, you can implement same thing using match, i just more like first form.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not a RESTful routes, you don't need `resources` block, use `match` on top-level of `routes.rb`:

```
match '/:slug/shipment/new', to 'shipments#new', via: [:get, :post]
```